# Integral of a square root involving polynomial and reciprocal polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I go about solving $\int \sqrt{1-x^2+\frac{1}{{1+x^2}}}dx$ I have tried u sub and trig sub but can't seem to simplify it enough, is this solvable?

The graph of this function looks quite similar to the graph of the ellipse $\sqrt{2}(x^2)+(y^2)=2$ above the x axis

Have gone in circles for the past hour and now I'm just curious if it is solvable, any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $x=\tan(t)$ gives $i\int  \sqrt{\tan(t)^4-2}\sec(t)dt$. You likely need [elliptic integrals](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/)

Comment: Were there bounds on this integral when you found it?